# TypeError: Type literal_string "WALLET_ADDRESS" is not implicitly convertible to expected type address

Tags: solidity, remix

Anyone know what this error means in Remix - Solidity IDE?

`address public constant WALLET = "A_WALLET_ADDRESS";`

```
TypeError: Type literal_string "A_WALLET_ADDRESS" 
is not implicitly convertible to expected type address.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out the address constant did not want a quoted string

The solution was:
`address public constant WALLET = A_WALLET_ADDRESS;`

If anyone can explain why, ill gladly accept the answer :)

I imagine its due to the strict type checking of Solidity variables. Giving `"0xValidAddress"` fails as its type is `"string"` whereas `0xValidAddress` passes the type check as a valid Ethereum address, therefore is allowed to pass on

Answer (score 1):

My case was updating

```
balances["0xValidAddress"] = _totalSupply;
```

TO

```
balances[0xValidAddress] = _totalSupply;
```